# Двоеточие перед одним словом это нормально?

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие

Приведите примеры грамотного использования такого, пожалуйста. Можно свои. Особенно когда перед словом с двоеточием не короткое предложение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно замечал нечто подобное в заголовках (для них есть отдельное правило):

*Двоеточие ставится в заголовках, распадающихся на две части с четким интонационным делением, отличающиеся смысловой насыщенностью, предельной краткостью, нередко и эмоциональной выразительностью. Первая часть называет общую проблему, место действия, лицо, а вторая — содержит конкретизацию названного в первой части: Экономическая реформа: опыт, проблемы, трудности; Разоружение: концепция, проблемы, механизм; Россия — Западная Европа: выгоды и перспективы сотрудничества.*

Во всех примерах выше нет именно одного слова. Но, наверное, можно придумать нечто подобное: Брат за брата: месть; Чужой среди своих: волчара. (Простите за тупые примеры, не удержался).

**С другой стороны, вам ничего не мешает использовать правило**, которое гласит, что *двоеточие ставится между двумя предложениями, не соединенными посредством союзов, если в первом предложении такими глаголами, как видеть, смотреть, слышать, знать, чувствовать и т. п., делается предупреждение, что далее последует изложение какого-нибудь факта или какое-нибудь описание.*

1. *И вот бакенщик и помощник-киргиз видят: плывут по реке две лодки.*
2. *Я знаю: в вашем сердце есть и гордость, и прямая честь.*
3. *Павел чувствует: чьи-то пальцы дотрагиваются до его руки выше локтя.*

**Например, с ходу можно придумать такое:**

1. И вот Андрей увидел: плывут.
2. Анастасия Ивановна закрыла дверь, а потом услышала: кричат.
3. Роман посмотрел на кота и понял: мёртв.

Answer (score 3):

Это может быть нормальным, потому что вот доказательство – примеры из литературы:

- *От этого страшного зрелища я почти обезумел; раз я никому уже не мог помочь, мне хотелось только одного: бежать* (Александр Дюма).
- *И еще достал одну бутылочку французского под названием: бонбон* (Николай Гоголь).
- *Остановят, все пропало, пропустят, тоже все пропало: запомнят* (Фёдор Достоевский).
- *Княжна никогда не думала об этом гордом слове: справедливость* (Лев Толстой).
- *И в карты не садись: продаст* (Александр Грибоедов).